# Search range won't return any records even though record is in database table

Tags: php, html, sql

The user goes to my webpage, enters in the range of categories and it's supposed to return all the categories in the table but it isn't. I created a page for them to add records to the table in the database and it works. So now I need the user to go to the search page and be able to look up the categories that were added to the database and for them to display. Everytime i try to search the categories, everything runs good but it says "No records returned".

```
 Category Search Look-Up


   <form method="get" action="NameOfFileHere.php">
   Please enter the beginning category: 
   <input type="text" name="BegCat"><br/>
   Enter ending category
   <input type="text" name="EndCat"><br/>

   <input type="submit">
   </form>



       <?php
      $BegCat = htmlentities($_GET["BegCat"]);
      $EndCat = htmlentities($_GET["EndCat"]);

      echo "Trying to return records with category between ". $BegCat ." and       ". $EndCat .".<br/>";

    echo "Connecting to database server.<br />";
    try {
        //variable stores the connection -> $conn
        //PDO is a php data object -> helps prevent SQL injection
        //host = Database server host name
        //username = name of READ ONLY user
        //password = that user's password
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=Database Info Here");
    } catch(PDOException $e) { //this should tell us if there was a connection problem
        echo "Error connecting to server: " . $e->getMessage();
        die;
    }
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connection to server succeeded.<br />";
    echo "Connecting to database Category...<br />";
    try {
        //if executing a query, NO USER ENTERED fields should be in query string!
        $conn->query("USE Database Name Here;");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error connecting to database: " . $e->getMessage();
        die;
    }
    echo "Connection to recipes database succeeded.<br />";
    //SQL statement WILL have any user-entered data, so BIND needed
    $SQL = "SELECT ID, Cat, Description FROM Category";
    $SQL .= " WHERE Cat >= :BegCat AND Cat <= :EndCat;";

    try {
        $sth = $conn->prepare($SQL);
        $sth->bindParam(":BegCat", $BegCat); 
        $sth->bindParam(":EndCat", $EndCat);

        $sth->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error selecting category records: " . $e->getMessage();
        die;
    }
    echo "Query executed successfully. <br />";
    //are there records in the set?
    if($sth->rowCount()==0) {
        echo "No records returned.<br />";
        die;
    } else {
        echo $sth->rowCount() . " records returned.<br />";
    }
    //$result is an array that holds the dataset
    while($result = $sth->fetch()) {
        //in an array, refer to column with string inside brackets ['rid']
        echo "Category ID: " . $result['ID'] . "<br />";
        echo "Category Name: " . $result['Cat'] . "<br />";
        echo "Description: " . $result['Description'] . "<br />";
        /*put lots link here*/
        echo "<a href='DeleteFileHere.php?ID=".$result['ID']."'>Delete Category ID ".$result['ID']."</a><br />";
        echo "<a href='UpdateFileHere.php?ID=".$result['ID']."'>Update Category ID ".$result['ID']."</a><br />";
    }
    ?>
```

Picture of Database Table 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaPkT.png)

Comment: What is `Cat`? Did you store it with conversion to entities?

Comment: Cat is short for Category, in the database that's what it's labeled as so I have to keep it the same.

Comment: It's basically the placeholder

Comment: I mean it is a string or integer?

Comment: I assigned it as a VarChar.

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs, DB records, and what you expect to be returned?

Comment: Yes, from my first page, the user can enter in the ID, Cat, and Description. It is then inserted into my Category table. Then I go to the second page where I search for a range of categories and then the records that are in the database table is returned. I will try to post a picture in the original post of what my database table looks like

Comment: This is the image of the table in my database https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaPkT.png

Comment: Also include what your `BegCat` and `EndCat` are.

Comment: BegCat=beginning category and EndCat=Ending Category

Comment: I mean your literal values. What are you testing with and what do you expect it to return? e.g. `electronics` and `travel`.

Comment: I was just using those three categories to test the program out to make sure it was working before I started adding more categories. I expect the search range to return the category, the id, and the description. So if I search between Travel and Food/Wine, I would expect it to return whatever categories are in between them if that makes sense?

Comment: `>=` and `<=` on strings are looking at the alphabetical value (I believe, or string length, check docs). I suspect noting is between the two literal values you are testing but I'm unclear what those are. If `Travel` first and `Food/wine` second that'd make sense. The `between` also is easier to use than `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: Would this be the correct line? WHERE Cat BETWEEN >= :BegCat AND Cat <= :EndCat;";

Comment: `WHERE Cat BETWEEN :BegCat AND :EndCat;` would be, but again with a string I don't know what behavior you are expecting/testing with.

Comment: I changed the statement line to this and then all of the records except entertainment displayed: $SQL = "SELECT ID, Cat, Description FROM Category";$SQL .= " WHERE Cat BETWEEN 'Entertainment' AND 'Travel';";

Comment: I'm going to try the line you suggested and see how it works! Also what do you mean by behavior?

Comment: What are you querying (you've added the query now so that is known), what is your data, what are you expecting.

Comment: I have a project where its supposed to act like a auction system, I am supposed to create a page where the backend users can go in, look up a category, have that category returned and others, then from there they should be able to delete/modify/update those categories.

Comment: I am using a data dictionary right now for my category table.